# Disable blueprint CSS for a div

Tags: css, frameworks, blueprint-css

I'm working on a webpage that involves using the Blueprint CSS Framework, as this framework focuses on all aspects of a webpage I can not achieve some things that would normally be quite simple. Basically all I would like to know is - is there a script or something that will allow me to disable a stylesheet for a single div on a webpage without editing the Framework altogether?

Thanks for any replies, I can fix this by changing the CSS although that would end up having to many issues in the long term.

Comment: No, you can't just "disable a stylesheet for a single div". Maybe you should add *specific details* about the problem you're facing so we can suggest a workable solution.

Comment: What styles are you looking to remove from this `<div>`? (Does Blueprint really set default styles for `<div>`s? Doesn’t sound like a very sensible approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can disable Blueprint for specific divs, since the framework is using basic HTML tags like Body, H1, etc... You would need to modify the Blueprint CSS ids for that.

Only thing that I can think right now (I'm not 100% sure it would work) is using an Iframe pointing to another file that would contain the div that you want to use. But then that document wouldn't inherit any css from your main one